# Difficulty with array? (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26)

Tags: java

I've been having some trouble with my array. I'm doing an encoding program, and when say I shift the letter "y" two places, which should be "a", I get an error. The same happens when I decode (shifting the letter to the left). Any advice?

Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/v3wjn793

Comment: Add the whole stactrace please! Which jar is needed for `MessageEncoder`? And give us the line where the `excption occurs.

Comment: Take a look at the modulo operator (`%`).

Comment: Ah, sorry! Give a moment while I edit that in the pastebin...

Comment: Why do you use "pastebin"? You can post code here directly.

Comment: Shift the letter "y" that is the 25th character in alphabet  two place, which should be the 27th character in alphabet. Unfortunately, alphabet has only 26 characters. You expect the letter 'a' that is first character in alphabet, you apply modulo operation in your mind. 27 % 26 = 1 .  If you use index in the range  between 0 to 25, no ArrayIndexOutOfBoudException will be raise.

Comment: @Christian, I'm not used to formatting the code here.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using mod operation to wrap back around

```
letters[ n % 26 ]

Uletters[n % 26 ]
```

Comment: You probably need `(n + 26) % 26` to handle left shifts.